# non zero dirichlet boundary condition entered in weak form

Tags: finite-element, julia

i am trying to write a julia code for linear elasticity in my case i dont have body force and traction but there is a nonzero drichlet bc(ubc) i want to engage the bc in weak form in linear part. is my linear and bilnear part as below

```
a = ε(v) ⊙ σ(u)
b = ubc * ε(v) ⊙ σ(v)
```

Comment: We'll probably need more details to help you -- it's not clear what your question is or what Julia package you're using. Are you asking if your weak form is correct or how to impose Dirichlet BCs?

Comment: The bilinear form for sure needs to be linear in $v$, but your second line is not.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a weak form with nonhomogeneous BCs, how to implement it in this Julia package, or both?